# Interpolate CSV data and mask with SHP file

Tags: shapefile, read.csv, spatial-interpolation

I want to interpolate an index that exist in bottom csv with kriging method, then plot and mask that map with shp file.

> ```
> lat        lon      B1
> 25.25      61.25    0.086
> 25.75      61.25    0.046
> 25.75      60.75    0.079
> 25.75      60.25    0.083
> .          .         .
> .          .         . 
> .          .         .
> ```

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from pykrige.ok import OrdinaryKriging
from pykrige.kriging_tools import write_asc_grid
import pykrige.kriging_tools as kt
File_path="C:/Users/user/Desktop/project/csv/mjo-gis.csv"
df= pd.read_csv(File_path)
df1=df[['LAT' , 'LON' , 'B1']]
lons=np.array(df1['LON']) 
lats=np.array(df1['LAT']) 
zdata=np.array(df1['B1'])
File_path2="C:/Users/user/Desktop/project/shp/Ostan/Ostan.shp"
Iran=gpd.read_file(File_path2)
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = Iran.total_bounds
xmin = xmin-0.01
xmax = xmax+0.01
ymin = ymin-0.01
ymax = ymax+0.01
grid_lon = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
grid_lat = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, 100)
OK = OrdinaryKriging(lons, lats, zdata, variogram_model='gaussian', verbose=True,                                  enable_plotting=False,nlags=20)
z1, ss1 = OK.execute('grid', grid_lon, grid_lat)
xintrp, yintrp = np.meshgrid(grid_lon, grid_lat) 
xnorm = (xintrp - xintrp.min()) / (xintrp.max() - xintrp.min())
ynorm = (yintrp - yintrp.min()) / (yintrp.max() - yintrp.min())
v = np.cos((xnorm * 2 - 1) * np.pi) + np.sin((ynorm * 2 - 1) * np.pi)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30,30))
Irangeom = Iran.geometry
contour = plt.contourf(xintrp, yintrp, z1,len(z1),cmap='RdBu',alpha = 0.8) 
plt.colorbar(contour)
Iran.plot(ax=ax,color='white' , alpha = 0.2, linewidth=5.5, edgecolor='black', zorder = 5)
plt.xticks(fontsize = 30, rotation=60)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 30)
plt.title('B1' ,fontsize = 40)
plt.show()
```

After plotting I want to mask outside shp file.